# If k is a positive integer, find the radius of convergence, R, of the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(n!)^{k+2}\cdot x^n}{((k+2)n)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(n!)^{k+2}\cdot x^n}{((k+2)n)!}$$

Hello, I'm having trouble finding the radius of convergence. I think I am close, but I can't finish the problem.

I used the ratio test:

$$\left|\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^{n}} \cdot \frac{((k+2)n)!}{((k+2)(n+1))!}\cdot\frac{((n+1)!)^{k+2}}{((n)!)^{k+2}}\right|$$

$$\left|x \cdot \frac{((k+2)n)!}{((k+2)(n+1))!}\cdot(n+1)^{k+2}\right|$$

Assuming this is correct, I am having trouble going further. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok well we have to do lots of things.. What you did is good. Now to proceed we all focus on the term

$$\frac{((k+2)n)!}{((k+2)(n+1))!}$$

We will make use of Stirling approximation (I hope you know what it is, it's fundamental)

$$((k+2)n)! = \sqrt{2\pi (k+2)n}\left(\frac{(k+2)n}{e}\right)^{(k+2)n}$$

$$((k+2)(n+1))! = \sqrt{2\pi (k+2)(n+1)}\left(\frac{(k+2)(n+1)}{e}\right)^{(k+2)(n+1)}$$

Then you simply do what you had to do in calculating the ratio.

**I will avoid to write the terms $x(n+1)^{k+2}$ until the end**

$$\frac{\sqrt{2\pi (k+2)n}\left(\frac{(k+2)n}{e}\right)^{(k+2)n}}{\sqrt{2\pi (k+2)(n+1)}\left(\frac{(k+2)(n+1)}{e}\right)^{(k+2)(n+1)}} = (k+2)^{-(k+2)}\frac{n^{n(k+2)}}{(n+1)^{(k+2)(n+1)}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}\cdot e^{k+2}$$

Now we introduce the terms we left behind, obtaining

$$x\cdot (k+2)^{-(k+2)}\frac{n^{n(k+2)}}{(n+1)^{(k+2)(n+1)}}\cdot (n+1)^{k+2}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}\cdot e^{k+2} $$

If you notice, we have the possibility of collecting some term with $(k+2)$ exponent, so we arrive to (I leave the algebra to you, it's simple):

$$\frac{x e^{k+2}}{(k+2)^{k+2}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}\cdot \left(\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}\right)^{k+2}$$

This is the final expression. Now we have to take the limit for $n \to \infty$ and to do that we recall the two most important limit that appear here:

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} = 1$$

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \left(\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}\right)^{k+2} = \frac{1}{e^{k+2}}$$

Inserting this in the formula above and we get:

$$R = \frac{x}{(k+2)^{k+2}}$$

**More on Stirling Approximation**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: We have not covered Stirling Approximation yet, but I was able to follow that. Thank you so much, that was fantastic!

Comment: You're welcome! Usually, Stirling approximation is something that one should know, because when $n$ is very large it works perfectly! ^^